# what is the maximum size of start_urls

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm just doing a project with scrapy.

I defined my `start_urls` as follows:

```
  start_urls = []
  for i in (1,10):
          for j in (1,10):
                  start_urls.append(base_url + '/' + str(i) + '/' + str(j) )
```

but for some reason, `scrapy` only picks up `4` links to crawl instead of all `100` links.

in this example I only crawl :
base_urls/1/1
base_urls/1/10
base_urls/10/1
base_urls/10/10

why is that? is there a limitation on `start_urls` in scrapy?

Comment: Doesn't exist such limitation; I would say the answer to this is in the stats.

Comment: @nramirezuy I just edited my question mate, would that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a `scrapy` problem.
`(1, 10)` in `Python` means a tuple which has 2 elements `1` and `10`. You may want to use `range(1, 10)` instead.

Also if you want 100 links, use either `range(10)` (gives `0`, `1`, ... , `9`)
 or `range(1, 11)` (gives `1`, `2`, ... , `10`)

Comment: haha mate, thanks a punch, only started cracking python... I feel stupid now :D

Comment: good catch, I thought it was something lost on the translation.